# How to show same data for multiple times in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

```
12/04/2022  Afternoon   19
12/04/2022  Morning     540
12/04/2022  Night       35
11/04/2022  Afternoon   1829
11/04/2022  Morning     207
11/04/2022  Night       361
```

Now, i need one more column, in which i want to show in this way.

```
12/04/2022      594
12/04/2022      594
12/04/2022      594
11/04/2022      2397
11/04/2022      2397
11/04/2022      2397
```

means i want to find sum of number three time for each date

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to calculate what time of the day does the task_id percentage is lower on each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, QUERY({A:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1 label sum(Col3)''"), {1, 2}, )))
```

[image]